# mpeg-dash real-time streaming delay from start

Tags: streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Hello I'm researching about realtime streaming with mpeg-dash, rtmp by using nginx-rtmp-module.

So when the client use rtmp the video is delay from start about 1-2 secs.

But when the client use mpeg-dash with dash.js I can see the delay from 
start is about 8 secs or more with `setLiveDelay(1)`.

This is my setup.

```
dash on;
dash_path /tmp/dash;
dash_fragment 2s;
dash_playlist_length 10s;
```

Is this is the cons of mpeg-dash about realtime streaming right?

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this is the cons of mpeg-dash about realtime streaming right?

It's an attribute of any segmented streaming.  HLS has the same problem.

There are tradeoffs to be made when choosing your streaming media technologies.  If latency actually matters to you, DASH is not the right choice.  Look into WebRTC.  If you need to stream one-to-many, DASH is certainly easier to do.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've try HLS and it's the same problem as you told. I'll try webRTC thank.